# Displaying times table using javascript

Tags: javascript

As I am new to JavaScript, I am a bit confused of using the for loops in JavaScript. I have tried the times table using the below JavaScript code, but I was unsuccessful in creating the times table for 1 to 9, as displayed in the image.

```
  var display = ""; // The table output HTML
  for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    var multiplier = 1;
    var result = i * 1;

    display += multiplier + " * " + i + " = " + result + "\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 " ;

  }

  document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = display;
```

I tried using nested for loops, but it left me with an error

This is where I have done with a single for loop

https://codepen.io/vbudithi/pen/LgEPwx

**I tried to get the output in the below form**

[image]

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: As you noticed, you'll have to use two `for` loops, nested. The one you used in your codepen works when `multiplier=1`. Now you should embed that loop into a loop in which `multiplier` goes from 1 to 9. You'll have to slightly adjust your inner loop so that `i` starts at `multiplier` instead of starting at 1, and you'll be done.

Comment: Ditto @NicolasB comment, and of course when falling out of that inner loop add a carrage return/line feed.

Comment: Thank you @NicolasB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like NicolasB said, wrapping the loop in another loop

```
var display = ""; // The table output HTML
for(j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
  for (i = j; i <= 9; i++) {
    var result = i * j;

    display += j + " * " + i + " = " + result + "\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 " ;

  }
  display += "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = display;
```

Comment: Yeah finally you made my day

Answer (score 2):

Use nested loop with break line. "< br >"

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yRyLje

```
var display = ""; 


for( i = 1; i < 10; i++){
   for (j = i; j < 10; j++) {

        display += i + " * " + j + " = " + j * i+ "\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0" ;

    }
  display +="<br>";
 }
document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = display;
```